# Using Inheritance to add on from parent class to child class

Tags: python

I have 2 classes, and I tried to add on the child class from parent class to convert to percentage from the letter counting

Original class:

```
class TextAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text
        self._processed_text = ""
        self._all_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
        self._cleaned_letters = []
        self._cleaned_letters_count = 0
        self._individual_letter_counts = {}
        self._top_5_letter_counts = []

    def _preprocess_text(self):
        self._cleaned_letters = list(filter(str.isalpha, self._text.upper()))
        self._cleaned_letters_count = len(self._cleaned_letters)
        self._individual_letter_counts = collections.Counter(self._cleaned_letters)
        self._top_5_letter_counts = self._individual_letter_counts.most_common(5)
        self._processed_text = " ".join(self._cleaned_letters)
    def analyze_text(self):
        self._preprocess_text()
        self._generate_report()
```

Inherited class to count letter in text in percentage:

```
class FrequencyAnalyzer(TextAnalyzer):
    def __init__(self, text, frequency_data):
        super().__init__(text)
        self._frequency_data = {}
        lines = frequency_data.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            char, percent = line.strip().split(',')
            self._frequency_data[char] = float(percent)
        self._letter_percentages = {}  # Store letter percentages here
        self._inferred_cipher_key = None

    def _calculate_letter_percentages(self):
        super()._preprocess_text()
        total_letters = sum(self._individual_letter_counts.values())
        sorted_letter_percentages = {}
        for letter in sorted(self._individual_letter_counts.keys()):
            count = self._individual_letter_counts[letter]
            percentage = (count / total_letters) * 100
            sorted_letter_percentages[letter] = percentage

        # Print the sorted letter percentages
        # print("Letter Frequencies (Sorted Alphabetically):")
        # for letter, percent in sorted_letter_percentages.items():
        #     print(f"{letter}: {percent:.3f}%")
        
        return sorted_letter_percentages
            
    def _generate_report(self):
        self._calculate_letter_percentages()
        print("Letter Percentages:")
        for char, encrypted_percentage in self._letter_percentages.items():
            reference_percentage = self._frequency_data.get(char, 0)  # Get the reference percentage for the current letter
            percentage_difference = abs(encrypted_percentage - reference_percentage)
            print(f"{char}: Encrypted: {encrypted_percentage:.2f}%, Reference: {reference_percentage:.2f}%, Difference: {percentage_difference:.2f}")


        print("Inferred Cipher Key:")
        for char, shift in self._inferred_cipher_key.items():
            print(f"{char}: {shift}")

        print("Letter Percentages:")
        for char, percentage in self._letter_percentages.items():
            print(f"{char}: {percentage:.2f}%")
            
            
    def analyze_text(self):
        self._preprocess_text()
        self._generate_report()
```

Main prgram:

```
                attempts = 0
                while attempts < 3:
                    input_file_name = input("Please enter the file you want to analyze: ")
                    if input_file_name.endswith('.txt') and os.path.exists(input_file_name):
                        input_text = ManageFile.openFile(input_file_name)
                        if input_text is None:
                            print("Error: Unable to read file.")
                            attempts += 1
                        else:
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid file name or file does not exist. Please include '.txt' extension.")
                        attempts += 1
                else:
                    print("Failed to read the file after 3 attempts. Returning to the main menu.")
                    continue  # Continue to the next iteration of the main menu loop

                
                analyzer = TextAnalyzer(input_text)
                #print(analyzer) 
                analyzer.analyze_text()
                #analyzer.perform_analysis()
                #input_text = Caesar.openFile(input_file_name)
                
                os.system("pause") # Get "Press any key to continue"
```

I would like to achieve inheritance by using preprocessing_text from parent class to count the letters and then the child class to add on by converting letters into percentage like

```
A,8.2
B,1.5
C,2.8
D,4.3
E,12.7
F,2.2
G,2.0
H,6.1
I,7.0
J,0.15
K,0.77
L,4.0
M,2.4
N,6.7
O,7.5
P,1.9
Q,0.095
R,6.0
S,6.3
T,9.1
U,2.8
V,0.98
W,2.4
X,0.15
Y,2.0
Z,0.074
```

Error:

```
Letter Percentages:
Inferred Cipher Key:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Data Structures\CA1\main.py", line 259, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Data Structures\CA1\main.py", line 238, in main
    analyzer.analyze_text()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Data Structures\CA1\caesar.py", line 422, in analyze_text
    self._generate_report()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Data Structures\CA1\caesar.py", line 412, in _generate_report
    for char, shift in self._inferred_cipher_key.items():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

** whats with the error and maybe my formatting for inheritance is wrong.**

I think maybe the way i convert encrypted text to letters to percentage is wrong whih is why i got

```
Inferred Cipher Key:
A: 3
B: 8
C: 0
D: 3

E: 7
G: 2
I: 0
J: 1
L: 0
M: 8
O: 6
P: 5
Q: 10
S: 0
T: 3
U: 2
V: 5
W: 5
X: 1
Z: 4
```

Encrypted text:
"Beqvstm, beqvstm tqbbtm abiz,
pwe Q ewvlmz epib gwc izm.

Cx ijwdm bpm asg aw pqop,
tqsm i lqiuwvl qv bpm asg."

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: I cant make use of inheritance to solve Obtaining the inferred cipher key.

Comment: @MichaelButscher

Comment: In `FrequencyAnalyzer.__init__` you set `self._inferred_cipher_key = None` and don't change it afterwards. The error is the consequence of this.